# Qt - Controlling external Process

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Currently I am starting an external process in Qt like this (btw I am using a windows machine):

```
 QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess();
 myProcess->setWorkingDirectory("C:/working/dir");
 myProcess->start("C:/working/dir/program.exe");
```

Everything works.

What I need, is to be able to start that program in the minimized state. Is this possible? if so, please help.

Thanks.

p.s. let me know if you need any more information

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK Qt doesn't have facilities for this kind of thing, but perhaps you can use the Windows START launcher.  Try:

`myProcess->start("START C:/working/dir/program.exe /MIN");`

It has other options, including `/MAX` and `/WAIT`

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true